# Stored type to function parameter

Tags: swift, generics, nested-generics

I face the following issue,

I have a swift function that takes a T.Type as parameter

```
public static func register<T:Decodable>(_ type:T.Type, clousure:@escaping()->NSDictionary){
public static func make<T:Decodable>(_ type:T.Type, _ overload:NSDictionary? = nil) -> T?{
```

I register it to a dictionary  of type

```
static var factories = [String: () -> NSDictionary]()
```

This way I can create a new object from a dictionary by just decoding it

when calling it this way `Factory.make(MyType.self)`

However, I want it to be a bit more powerful and be able to do factories from a dictionary containing another class

```
Factory.make(MyType.self) {[
   "name": A random name,
   "subObject": SubOject.self
}]
```

And here is when I face the problem, to detect this suboject and call make to it

```
finalDict.allKeys.forEach { key in
    if let className = finalDict[key] as? AnyClass {
        print(className)
        //finalDict[key] = Factory.make(className.self)
        //finalDict[key] = Factory.make(className)
    }
}
```

I can't do that, I've tried casting to AnyClass, AnyObject.Type... but them all make the compiler fail,

Do you know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated but this is Swift: Don't use *typeless* `NS...` Foundation collection types.

Comment: Hehe I tried but I was really hard to decode from a [AnyHashable: Any] it then... since you need it all typed and I wanted full flexibility here..

Comment: Why `[AnyHashable: Any]`? Both JSON and PropertyList require `String` keys.

Comment: Is there a way to get json data from `[AnyHashable : Any]` type?

Comment: A JSON compliant dictionary must be `[String:Any]`.

Comment: But any is not encodable

Comment: How can `NSDictionary` be encodable?

Comment: With Objective C JSON Serialization, the problem in swift is that I want a dict where I can store types or even closures, and then I would need the any, but this is not encodable, however, I want to transform the clousures and Types before encoding too (but in objective-c I don't need all that type safety)

Comment: The `Codable` protocol requires static types because the magic relies on a relationship between the struct members and the dictionary keys. `JSONSerialization` (in both ObjC and Swift) decodes to either array or dictionary  of 4 different value types which is comparatively very simple.